# creating a customer class - it wont allow me to print detail?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am practicing with class creation. In the code below I want to print the details of customer1. I apologize before had ... I am sure this is very basic but cant seem to print the details of customer1????

```
class customer():

    def _init_(self, Fname, Sname, age, post_code, party_size, return_customer):

        self.Fname = Fname
        self.Sname = Sname
        self.age = age
        self.post_code = post_code
        self.party_size = party_size
        self.return_customer = return_customer

    def print_detail():

        print(self.Fname)
        print(self.Sname)
        print(self.age)
        print(self.post_code)
        print(self.party_size)
        print(return_customer)


def create_customer():

    customer1 = customer('David', 'Lamb', '28', 'SA20GB', '3', 'Y')


create_customer()
```

Comment: You never call `print_detail`

Comment: ah thanks, I have added that call in now and it says

Comment: NameError: name 'print_detail' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things I can see here straight away:

```
    def _init_(self, Fname, Sname, age, post_code, party_size, return_customer):
```

`__init__` is a special name, and requires two underscores

```
    def print_detail():
```

The methods of your class are automatically passed the `self` parameter, you need to include this.

```
        print(return_customer)
```

This line needs the `self` reference as with the previous lines.

```
def create_customer():

    customer1 = customer('David', 'Lamb', '28', 'SA20GB', '3', 'Y')


create_customer()
```

You never call `customer1.print_detail()`.

In all, your final code should be as follows:

```
class customer():
    def __init__(self, Fname, Sname, age, post_code, party_size, return_customer):
        self.Fname = Fname
        self.Sname = Sname
        self.age = age
        self.post_code = post_code
        self.party_size = party_size
        self.return_customer = return_customer

    def print_detail(self):
        print(self.Fname)
        print(self.Sname)
        print(self.age)
        print(self.post_code)
        print(self.party_size)
        print(self.return_customer)


def create_customer():
    customer1 = customer('David', 'Lamb', '28', 'SA20GB', '3', 'Y')
    customer1.print_detail()

create_customer()
```

Comment: Great, I am very greatful for your help!! I havent used this site much! How do i show my appreciation. Is there a like option or something similar? Thanks again

Comment: No worries @David, glad to help. To the left of my answer you'll see arrows (that let you vote an answer up or down) and a tick (that lets you mark the answer as "correct").